# Solve $x''(t)-\frac{x^2(t)}{\sin t}=\frac{\sin\left( (t-1)^2\right)}{\sin t}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following Cauchy problem:
$$x''(t)-\frac{x^2(t)}{\sin t}=\frac{\sin\left( (t-1)^2\right)}{\sin t}$$
with $x'(1)=x(1)=0$.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the numerator on the right $\sin\bigl((t-1)^2\bigr)$, or what is more commonly written $\sin^2(t-1)$?

Comment: I've edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: is there a typo in your equation?

Comment: it is not clear if you mean $\sin(t-1)^2$ or $\sin((t-1)^2)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Try reloading the page.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Where does this problem come from? Are there initial conditions?

Comment: Yes, excuse me. I did not think they could be important.

Comment: No problem; thanks for including them. Initial conditions can dramatically change the solution of a differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a numerical solution:

[image: ODE solution]

Looks like maybe a boundary layer flow profile.

Some MATLAB:

```
x0 = [0; 0];
f = @(t,x)[x(2); 1/sin(t)*(x(1)^2+sin((t-1)^2))];

[tout,xout] = ode45(f,[1 5],x0);

plot(xout(:,1),xout(:,2),'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('x_1')
ylabel('x_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maple finds no solution.  I doubt very much that there is a closed-form solution.  Do you have reason to think that there is?

EDIT: With the added initial conditions, you still won't find a closed-form
solution, but you can have a series solution

$$ x(t) =  {\frac {1}{12\,\sin \left( 1 \right) }} \left( t-
1 \right) ^{4}-{\frac {\cos \left( 1 \right) }{20\, \left( \sin
 \left( 1 \right)  \right) ^{2}}} \left( t-1 \right) ^{5}+O \left( 
 \left( t-1 \right) ^{6} \right) 
$$

or a numerical solution.

Comment: I second your doubt!